# how to fix ioctl permissions denied error?

Tags: root-access, magisk

I searched in lots of websites/forums but did not find a solution for this problem, and this site is last chance, this is problem:
This problem have several other users too.
my phone is Galaxy S7 Edge , exynos, Oreo 8.0 (Stock ROM), rooted with magisk latest version.
root works well in other applications.
In pentesting applications like csploit, Network Spoofer, WifiKill and others  root works well(grants permission)  but when start using options of app(for example, arp spoofing, network sniffer, MITM, etc) drops same error:
[ERROR] Unable to retrieve local hardware address libnet ( ioctl: Permission denied )
what to do? Can this issue fixed? or exactly which permission is it?

Also one interesting thing, when I installed old version of WifiKill app it worked - killed wifi connection.

Comment: If old version works it indicates that the problem is with the new version of app(s), probably with latest release of `libnet` since all apps are  based on it. So the only one who can help you with this is the app developer. For us `[ERROR] Unable to retrieve local hardware address libnet ( ioctl: Permission denied )` is not enough to figure out why `libnet` was unable to get MAC address and which `ioctl` failed. More logs are required. If command-line execution is possible get `strace` output.

Comment: I do not know well commands, but I found this app CatLog and recorded logs, maybe its what is needed for this situation? I cut several lines about application(network spoofer).

Comment: 02-29 02:11:49.571 V/android-netspoof(10524): cout: Current Wifi IP: 192.168.0.100
02-29 02:11:49.571 V/android-netspoof(10524): cout: Current subnet: 192.168.0.0
02-29 02:11:49.571 V/android-netspoof(10524): cout: Subnet mask: 255.255.255.0
02-29 02:11:49.571 V/android-netspoof(10524): cout: Enabling ip_forward

Comment: 02-29 02:11:49.572 V/android-netspoof(10524): cout: Starting ARP Spoofing
02-29 02:11:49.572 V/android-netspoof(10524): cout: arpspoof -i wlan0 -t 192.168.0.102 192.168.0.1
02-29 02:11:49.572 V/android-netspoof(10524): cout: iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
02-29 02:11:49.572 V/android-netspoof(10524): cout: iptables -I natctrl_FORWARD -j RETURN
02-29 02:11:49.572 V/android-netspoof(10524): cout: iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
02-29 02:11:49.572 V/android-netspoof(10524): cout: iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3128

Comment: 02-29 02:11:49.572 V/android-netspoof(10524): cout: dSploit ArpSpoofer.
02-29 02:11:49.572 V/android-netspoof(10524): cout: 
02-29 02:11:49.573 V/android-netspoof(10524): cout: [ERROR] Unable to retrieve local hardware address libnet ( ioctl: Permission denied ).

Answer (score 1):

finally, I solved this problem , it needed permissive selinux mode, so I installed custom kernel on my phone and everything works perfect.