# WIFIKILL Permission denied

Tags: applications, wi-fi, samsung, root-access, samsung-galaxy-s8+

I have an s8+ rooted device i've installed wifikill and gave it super user from magisk after that i opened it, pressed on the start button and it gave me an err message saying(sock_fd, siocgifhwaddr, i) permission denied.

i hope someone can let me know what's going on and help me with a solution.

Comment: It's hard to guess. At least share some logs. Looks like duplicate of this (from `siocgifhwaddr`): https://android.stackexchange.com/q/221649/218526

Comment: If you are talking about a specific app please include a link to the app in Google PlayStore if it is listed there.