# ERROR Unable to retrieve local hardware address libnet (ioctl: Permission denied). iptables (2) failed

Tags: magisk

hi I tried to install network spoofer but it gives me this error and not only with this app but also with others it knows how to solve I already have the root

Comment: Duplicate of https://android.stackexchange.com/q/221649/218526

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to fix ioctl permissions denied error?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/221649/how-to-fix-ioctl-permissions-denied-error)